# Symfony 2.8 (Doctrine) Strange Behavior for OneToMany (Users, Photos)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have strange behavior with 2 entities **Users** and **Photos**.

When I run my query to get information about the users including a left join for the photos I receive this kind of result

```
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'usernameCanonical' => string 'unsparing' (length=9)
      'username' => string 'unsparing' (length=9)
      'filename' => string '1.jpg' (length=5)
      'width' => int 500
      'height' => int 600
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'usernameCanonical' => string 'unsparing' (length=9)
      'username' => string 'unsparing' (length=9)
      'filename' => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
      'width' => int 600
      'height' => int 400
```

but the result I want to get (at least with the previous versions of Doctrine) would be something like this:

```
array (size=5)
  'usernameCanonical' => string 'unsparing' (length=9)
  'username' => string 'unsparing' (length=9)
  'photos'   => array
  (
    0   =>  array 
            'filename' => string '2.jpg' (length=5)
            'width' => int 600
            'height' => int 400,
    1   =>  array 
            'filename' => string '3.jpg' (length=5)
            'width' => int 600
            'height' => int 400
  )
```

I think the relationship needs to be **OneToMany** from the point of view for a User (User can have many photos) and for **Photo** it needs to be **OneToOne** but if I use **OneToOne** it throws some errors.

Here are the entities classes:

**User**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="fos_user.birth_date.blank", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     */
    protected $birthDate;

    /**
     * var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Photos", mappedBy="userId")
     */
    protected $photos;
}
```

**Photos**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Photos
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="photos")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PhotosRepository")
 */
class Photos
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $userId;
}
```

This is the query that I am running:

```
public function getUserBySlug($slug)
  {
    $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')

      ->select('u.usernameCanonical, u.username')

      ->addSelect('p.filename, p.width, p.height')

      ->where('u.usernameCanonical = :slug')

      ->leftJoin('u.photos', 'p')

      ->setParameter('slug', $slug)

      ->getQuery();

    return $user->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
  }
```

Comment: Why are you creating your own query instead of `findBy(['usernameCanonical' => $slug])`?

Comment: Go with select('u', 'p') and remove addSelect.

Comment: @MateuszSip this doesn't matter and kingkero I want to get the photos as well that's why I am not doing this

Comment: @Unsparing if you have a relationship and you want to get the photos you can simply do `$user->getPhotos()` on the result of `$userRepository->findBy(['usernameCanonical' => $slug])` that's the point that kingkero is making. You are writing a query for something the ORM will already do for you.

Comment: @Unsparing
It does matter.
`By default when you run a DQL query in Doctrine and select only a subset of the fields for a given entity, you do not receive objects back. Instead, you receive only arrays as a flat rectangular result set, similar to how you would if you were just using SQL directly and joining some data.`

You actually only need to select entity aliased as 'u'.

@skrilled
When you get an entity through simple repository->find* just to invoke a relationship getter then, you actually run two queries instead of one.

Comment: @MateuszSip fair point - in OPs case won't his left join result in him only getting one picture too though?

Comment: @skrilled no, he will get a nice array/collection.